# How to change URL id with name but i want to pass ID and it shows that Name corresponding with id in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I repeater Item bound create a hyperlink URL in this i pass ID but when it's clicked by user it's pass ID on that page but in URL shows it's name.
Example like :

> localhost:50636/Products/Categories/Categories.aspx/?mc=1&cs=3&mid=1

Now the client want to look like this :

> localhost:50636/Products/Categories/xyzname/abcfv/ufo

I am trying but its not success can any one please help

```
protected void Rep_BindMenuItem_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        tblMenuCategory dataItem = (tblMenuCategory)e.Item.DataItem;
        HyperLink Menu = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLinkMenu");
        Menu.Text = dataItem.MenuCategory;
        int MenuId = dataItem.MenuCategoryID;
        Repeater repeatercategory = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("RepBindMenuCategItem");
        repeatercategory.DataSource = BLCategory.CategoryLoadByMenuId(MenuId);
        repeatercategory.DataBind();

        //Menu.NavigateUrl = string.Concat("~/Products/Categories/Categories.aspx/?mc=", MenuId.ToString() + "&cs=" + 0 + "&mid=" + MenuId.ToString());

        Response.RedirectToRoute("Selected Menu", new { Menuname = Menu.Text, mc = MenuId.ToString(), cs = 0, mid = MenuId.ToString() });
    }
}
```

In `Global.asax` I passed value  liked this

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

after that I passed

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Selected Menu", "{Menuname}/{mc}/{cs}/{mid}", "~/Products/Categories/Categories.aspx");
}
```

Comment: whats the error? `not success` means?

Comment: from my side its working well

Comment: It means when user click then want to redirect page with that functionalities, But at that when project is run it goes to that page thats issue

Comment: in your `repeater` all of urls are prepared and after clicking some item in repeater then user goes to respective url, m i right?

Comment: Yes it goes to that page with that id which is passed in Menu.navigateurl but it shows that name in URL not ID.

Comment: Yes it goes to that page with that id which is passed in Menu.navigateurl but i want to shows respective value of that parameter in URL not ID

Comment: Please help me in this i have only 8 hour to complete this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178015/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-ershoaib).

Comment: please provide data that is bounded to repeater so I'll prepare answer for you :)

Comment: Add those data in question

Comment: ?? Data i already post Repeater itemdataboud data .

Comment: means i want `xyzname/abcfv/ufo` this data. where is it?

Comment: That is came from Database corresponding to that Id     tblMenuCategory dataItem = (tblMenuCategory)e.Item.DataItem;      Menu.Text = dataItem.MenuCategory;
        int MenuId = dataItem.MenuCategoryID;

Comment: Can you able to use database call like 'getById' inside method repeater. If yes then call it and after getting data just replace strings in place of ids

Comment: No, Because at the time of repeater binding i just create a link that goes to another page . So when user click on that link that time i want to replace .

Comment: No dont do like this, its hard to manage to you, if you can call 'getById' in repeater and prepare a link before user click then you can get rid from your problem but if you say you have to create at the time of user click then while creating the link the user already redirected to another page with ids got it?

Comment: Ok just wait i'll add the answer for you :)

Comment: Hey buddy are u getting any solution..??

Comment: I have the solution that i gave you in above comment but anyways I'll try for more

Comment: In above comment which u give suggestion can u give me in the code form i will try then...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here I guess you have already menu present in your database or any other resource and your menu has below fields like in class

```
public class MyMenu
{
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public string MenuText { get; set; }
    public string MC { get; set; }
    public string CS { get; set; }
    public string MID { get; set; }
}
```

And then you have to create one method that will give you particular menu with Id from database or any other resource like

```
public MyMenu GetMenuById(int MenuId)
{
    //Database or repository call to get your menu data with menuId
}
```

You will be use the above method like below

```
protected void Rep_BindMenuItem_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        tblMenuCategory dataItem = (tblMenuCategory)e.Item.DataItem;
        **HyperLink Menu * * = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLinkMenu");
        Menu.Text = dataItem.MenuCategory;
        int MenuId = dataItem.MenuCategoryID;

        //Get menu by calling below method with menuid
        MyMenu myMenu = GetMenuById(MenuId);

        Repeater repeatercategory = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("RepBindMenuCategItem");
        repeatercategory.DataSource = BLCategory.CategoryLoadByMenuId(MenuId);
        repeatercategory.DataBind();

        //Bind those menu data to below parameters values 
        Response.RedirectToRoute("Selected Menu", new { Menuname = myMenu.MenuText, mc = myMenu.MC, cs = myMenu.CS, mid = myMenu.MID });
    }
}
```

Try once may it help you.

Comment: @amit kumar, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: before going with above answer first show me the data in `tblMenuCategory dataItem = (tblMenuCategory)e.Item.DataItem;` this line